# Mongoose - Update a document's map

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
    ...
    friends: {
        type: Map,
        of: String
    },
    ...
```

I am creating a game where you can add friends, so I want to store friend's username and ID in that map.
When I do

```
const requestantFriends = await UserData.findOne({userId: requestantData._id})

await UserData.findOneAndUpdate({userId: requestantData._id}, {friends: requestantFriends.friends.set(targetData._id, "test")}, {new: true})
```

nothing seems to happen. If I check the database, it still says *Map(0) {}*. How can I update a document's map and save it?

I've also tried

```
const requestantFriends = await UserData.findOne({userId: requestantData._id})

await requestantFriends.friends.set(targetData._id, "test")
await requestantFriends.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the 'friends' map is a field in the UserData model.

Here's the code!

```
await UserData.findOneAndUpdate({userId: requestantData._id}, {
  $set: {
    [`friends.${targetData._id}`]: "test",
  }
});
```

First, we find the document whose `userId` matches `requestantDate._id`. Then, we use the MongoDB `$set` operator to add a new key-value pair. We wrap the key in brackets to indicate that its value incorporates a variable, and then we use backticks to create a template literal so that we can insert the variable key name. Finally, we provide a value and close everything out!

Comment: Nice explaining the solution.

Comment: Perfect. Even ChatGPT did not come up with anything useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores data using [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), which does not have a `Map` type.

When Mongoose saves a document containing a map, it is stored in MongoDB as an embedded object.

If you retrieve the object using `find`, Mongoose will reconstitute the object as a map, and you would then need to use `get` and `set` to modify the contents.

When using `findOneAndUpdate`, or any of the `update` variants, Mongoose sends the operation to MongoDB for it to perform on the server side.

The operation that MongoDB would understand is `$set`, so the update should look like:

```
await UserData.findOneAndUpdate({userId: requestantData._id}, {$set: {"friends._id": "test"})
```